# I want to stay on dashboard if local storage has access token and redirect to login if not

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am doing it but page continues to refresh as i have local storage token. Its JS that i am using for it.
[![Here is the image i dont want to get back to login page if there is token in local storage][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwtcP.png
So here is the full code and this is working fine all i need is to set the check if the token is present in local storage then stay otherwise get back to login page

```
<html lang="en" style="height: auto;"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>AdminLTE 3 | DataTables</title>
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&amp;display=fallback">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.1/axios.js"integrity="sha512-SXo2rCaEJmbAPoxtaSjW+/hLaVCMAJ1CX8XnIP02x6/LIaWQp4GipKxQhBwL8Tn5U/K+lD9AaM4f4mXJdKnDQw=="crossorigin="anonymous"referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9f98b6568d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body >
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light ml-0 ">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
          <a href="/admin/view_hotels" class="nav-link">View Hotels</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
          <a href="/add/hotels" class="nav-link">Add Hotels</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
          <a href="https://thewordyboy.com/gift-store-about-us/" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

  


        <li class="nav-item">
          
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" onclick="logout();" role="button">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket "></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  
    
  
    <div class="content-wrapper ml-0" style="min-height: 2080.12px;">
      <section class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <h1>DataTables</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
  
      <!-- Main content -->
      <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h3 class="card-title">DataTable with minimal features &amp; hover style</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><table  class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable dtr-inline" role="grid">
                    <thead>
                    <tr role="row"><th>Id</th><th >Name</th><th >Email</th><th>Password</th><th>Retype</th><th>Contact</th><th>Actions</th></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="data">
                      <script>
                       
  axios
    .get(
      "https://localhost:8000/allusers")
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
              document.getElementById('data').innerHTML+=`<tr class="odd">
                      <td class="dtr-control sorting_1" tabindex="0">${response.data[i].id}</td>
                      <td>${response.data[i].name}</td>
                      <td>${response.data[i].email}</td>
                      <td>${response.data[i].password}</td>
                      <td>${response.data[i].cpassword}</td>
                      <td >${response.data[i].contact}</td>                                                                                         
                      <td ><a href="/user/delete/${response.data[i].id}"><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a><a href='/user/update?id=${response.data[i].id}&name=${response.data[i].name}&email=${response.data[i].email}&password=${response.data[i].password}&retype=${response.data[i].cpassword}&contact=${response.data[i].contact}'><button class="btn btn-primary ml-3">Update</button></a></td>
                      `
      }
     
  })
  
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

                      </script>
                    
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
  
              <div class="card">
                
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
    <footer class="main-footer">
      <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-block">
        <b>Version</b> 3.1.0
      </div>
      <strong>Copyright © 2014-2021 <a href="https://adminlte.io">AdminLTE.io</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
    </footer>
  
    <!-- Control Sidebar -->
    
    <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
  </div>
  <!-- ./wrapper -->
  
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
  <script src="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/jszip/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/pdfmake/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/pdfmake/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE App -->
  <script src="/assets/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $('#example2').DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "searching": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "responsive": false,
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
 const data=localStorage.getItem('token')
 if(data===null)
 {
  window.location.href='/login'
 }
 else{
  
 }

    function logout(){
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
      axios
    .get(
      "https://localhost:8000/logout",{
        headers: { Authorization:localStorage.getItem('token') }
      })
    .then((response) => {
      window.location.href='/login'
    })
    }
  </script>
  
  
  </body></html>
```

login.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>AdminLTE 3 | Log in</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&amp;display=fallback"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/assets/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/dist/css/adminlte.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body class="login-page" style="min-height: 496.781px">
    <div class="login-box">
      <div class="login-logo">
        <a href="/assets/index2.html"><b>Admin</b>LTE</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body login-card-body">
          <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input
              type="email"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
            />
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input
              type="password"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Password"
              name="password"
              id="password"
            />
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
              <div class="icheck-primary">
                <input type="checkbox" id="remember" />
                <label for="remember"> Remember Me </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <button onclick="login()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                Sign In
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <p class="mb-1">
            <a href="forgot-password.html">I forgot my password</a>
          </p>
          <p class="mb-0">
            <a href="register.html" class="text-center">
              Register a new membership</a
            >
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="w-100 h-100" id="demo">


    <script src="/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.1/axios.js"
      integrity="sha512-SXo2rCaEJmbAPoxtaSjW+/hLaVCMAJ1CX8XnIP02x6/LIaWQp4GipKxQhBwL8Tn5U/K+lD9AaM4f4mXJdKnDQw=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script>
          function login() {
            
            axios
              .post(
                "https://localhost:8000/login",
                {
                  email: document.getElementById('email').value,
                  password: document.getElementById('password').value,
                },
                {
                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                }
              )
              .then((response) => {
              localStorage.setItem('token',response.data.token);
              console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
                 if(localStorage.getItem('token')!=='undefined' ){
                  if(response.data.data==='f180111@nu.edu.pk'){
                    window.location.href="/dashboard"
                  }
                  else{
                    window.location.href="/userDashboard"
                  }
                 
                 }
                 else{
                  window.location.href="/signup"
                 }
          })
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to stay on page dont change `location.href`. Just remove that line.

Comment: no i want to check if the local storage has token than stay on page otherwise return to login

Comment: Thats what I am saying.  Just remove the ELSE block.

Comment: if i remove the else statement and call login url then it sets me to login page and i dont want that

Comment: i want if there is token in local storage then remain at dashboard page wether i call login it redirect automatically to dashboard

Comment: Otherwise if i dont have have token redirect me to login

Comment: Please help me with it i need iits solution

Comment: Then we need to see the rest of your code. In general all you need is to check if token is NOT present and then redirect to login page. However you need to SET token somewhere

Comment: I have sent the whole code

Comment: you can see the code now please help me with it

Comment: We can eaily do it on react js using use effects but dont know how to do it on plain js

Comment: Where do you actually SET the "token"?

Comment: i set the token in localstore by name token you can see the ss

Comment: There is no `.setItem("token", ...)` in your code...

Comment: I have set it on login let me show it as well

Comment: Please see it i have uploaded it as well

Comment: You need to verify that the token is properly set.